# constantly checking if a condition is true or false

Tags: python

I'm new to python and programming in general and I am currently taking a course on Udemy. One of the projects is to create a pick your own adventure game. I've been doing pretty
well until I came across something that has been picking at me. I wanted to display text depending on whether or not you have died by changing the condition of death from False to True. I know I can just add you died after the if/else statement with a print function but I wanted to make it a bit more challenging. Here's an example.

```
death = False
if death == True:
  print("\nYou died")

choice_1 = input("left or right:\n")
if choice_1 == "left":
  death = False
  print("*The next piece of dialogue*")
else:
  death = True
  print("*The next piece of dialogue*")
```

It would then print "you died" after the next piece of dialogue if the death changed to True.

Comment: You might want to create a function for when your character dies. Then, instead of reassigning your death variable each time, you can call the function and it will print the message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you're looking to do is constantly run the choices until `death = True` you just need to use a while loop before your if statements. This will constantly run the input until the value of death changes to True.

```py
def player_died()
   print('Do whatever you want to happen when player dies in this function')


death = False
while death == False:
    choice_1 = input("left or right:\n")

    if choice_1 == 'left':
        death = False
        print("*The next piece of dialogue*")

    elif choice_1 == 'right':
        death = True
        print("\nYou died")
        #This will break the while loop
        player_died()
```

Whatever additional things you wish to do after death = True, I would make a new function for that situation like def player_died(), and call that function under the 'You died' print. The while loop will end, and you will go to the next function.

If you wish to return back to that loop, AFTER you do something else, then change player_died() call to death = player_died() - and have the function return False, and remove the death=True above it.

This will allow you to execute whatever additional actions you want to do in the function, and when all of that is complete it will return back to the while loop and start over.